# Basic Aurelia Setup

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am follwing this: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1

I just Downloaded The Basic Aurelia Setup and I am running in my localhost.

I tought downloading the basic setup will be running normal without me do anything.

what I am missing?

I got this error in my console:

```
index.html:18 GET http://0.0.0.0:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
system.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/src/main.ts 404 (Not Found)

Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/src/main.ts
  Error loading http://localhost:8000/src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow the tutorial until the end. The ZIP file is not ready to run, it simply provides some basic structure. You still need to add the app source on your own (as it is shown in the tutorial).

As soon as you have finished the tutorial, you should be able to see an application.

A faster way to get a running app (without following the complete tutorial) is to use the Aurelia CLI:

1. Install NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Install Aurelia-CLI: `npm install aurelia-cli -g`
3. Create a project: `au new` (follow the steps described)
4. `cd <project dir> && au run`

Comment: thanks so much man, you clarify something what aurelia team and creators could not do for a novice with no knowledge in aurelia. OMG thanks so much, very helpfull